# Converting default OS with Wake on Lan (specific case)

Tags: bootloader, wake-on-lan

My desktop has two OS, linux ubuntu and WINDOWS 7, on separate HDDs. 
Bootloader is on linux. 
This computer is accessed remotely with Wake on Lan (WOL).

Wanting to freely choosing OS  when turning on the desktop, I tried following a Blog [here:](http://marshallhut.blogspot.kr/2008/06/dual-booting-with-wake-on-lan.html)

It seems "setting default OS from LINUX to WINDOWS" worked fine through grub setting, (Default 0 => Default 4)

But there's no way to access linux HDD (for control of bootloader) on WINDOWS. (I think this is due to HDD format.)
So I can't find way to set default OS to Linux again.

Can anyone help me  with this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by using Grub-reboot, referencing a webpage.
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/how-to-reboot-in-windows-from-ubuntu.html